# Converting MultiIndex Pandas DataFrame to Pivot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, pivot-table

Seems like this should be easy, but I cannot get it to work for the life of me.

I have a dataframe for stock data like below. How can I convert the below dataframe into a pivot table with the date as the rows, stock symbols as the columns, and Adj Close as the values (picture at bottom)

I am getting the dataframe with this code:
`pricing = web.DataReader(['MSFT', 'AAPL'], 'yahoo', datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1), datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 10))`

DataFrame
[image: DataFrame]
Pivot Table

[image: Pivot Table]

**EDIT:**

If I just do `pricing = web.DataReader(['MSFT', 'AAPL'], 'yahoo', datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1), datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 10))['Adj Close']` then I run into problems using .loc[] to grab data using another pivot's index.

I have a second pivot (shown below) and when I try to do pricing.loc[pivot2.index] I get an error.

[image: Pivot 2]

Error:

> KeyError: "None of [DatetimeIndex(['1999-01-01', '2000-01-01', '2003-01-01', '2004-01-01',\n               '2005-01-01', '2006-01-01', '2007-01-01', '2008-01-01',\n               '2009-01-01', '2010-01-01', '2011-01-01', '2012-01-01',\n               '2013-01-01', '2014-01-01', '2015-01-01', '2016-01-01',\n               '2017-01-01', '2018-01-01', '2019-01-01'],\n              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', freq=None)] are in the [index]"

Comment: From the  "EDIT" what is the error you are getting, and are the indexes of your pivot2 the same as pricing?  You may consider using `reindex` instead of .loc if there are missing indexes in pricing.

Comment: added error. I'm guessing it is because pricing will not always have the index that pivot2 is passing in since pivot2 is always passing in the 2nd day of the year as the date, but the market isn't always open on the 2nd day of the year, so there won't be an input for that day. Is it possible to easily use the closest date, if the passed in index doesn't work? Or will I need to update the pricing dataframe to include data for every day?

Comment: You can use `pricing.reindex(pivot2.index)` and this will return NaN for thos missing indexes and use something like `ffill` or `fillna` with at predetermine value.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
pricing['Adj Close']
```

where,

```
pricing = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(50,75,(10,6)), 
                  index=pd.date_range('01/2/20', periods=10, freq='D'),
                 columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Adj Close', 'Close', 'High'],['MSFT', 'AAPL']]))

           Adj Close      Close      High     
                MSFT AAPL  MSFT AAPL MSFT AAPL
2020-01-02        67   71    58   60   50   53
2020-01-03        54   59    64   72   62   50
2020-01-04        51   53    56   70   63   51
2020-01-05        64   71    74   62   68   62
2020-01-06        74   68    69   71   60   62
2020-01-07        55   55    51   70   74   72
2020-01-08        60   58    74   70   73   69
2020-01-09        51   58    72   54   50   61
2020-01-10        64   56    74   52   59   57
2020-01-11        55   50    68   61   60   59
```

Using [Basic indexing on axis with MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#basic-indexing-on-axis-with-multiindex) we can just select 'Adj Close' at level 0.

```
pricing['Adj Close']
```

Output:

```
            MSFT  AAPL
2020-01-02    66    51
2020-01-03    67    67
2020-01-04    74    74
2020-01-05    73    66
2020-01-06    68    52
2020-01-07    67    50
2020-01-08    73    54
2020-01-09    66    52
2020-01-10    62    73
2020-01-11    61    71
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This causes me to run into another problem. Added an edit to original question

Comment: @connorvo See comment in the question.